# How to select the most recent file?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to grab the most recent file with `src` in every subdirectory.

This is the task I have :

```
gulp.task('compile', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/jade/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Is there a way to get the freshest JS with gulp src ?

Comment: how do you mean, you want to order by date modified, or you only want the most recent changed one? Then why have these files inside your source folder? Do you care about synchronous tasks or not?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want one file but it has to be the most recent one. It can be sync.

Comment: was the answer of any help to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without really having used gulp so far, what you should do would be something like:

- Find all the files you wish to compile
- send them to the `src` method (which takes a string, or an array of files or a stream)

One of my problems was how to handle the glob style path, so for that I installed the [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) npm package in my local package.json

What I then did was, get all the files using `glob( path, callback )`, filter those according to the last modified using `fs.stat` and the `mtime` or `mtimeMs` and only keeping the last one

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

async function getFileLastModifiedBy( file ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.stat( file, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        reject( err );
        return;
      }
      resolve( stats.mtimeMs );
    });
  } );
}

async function filterByNewest( input ) {
  const filesByModifiedBy = {};
  for (let file of input) {
    let directory = path.dirname( file );
    let lastModifiedBy = await getFileLastModifiedBy( file );
    if (!filesByModifiedBy[directory] || filesByModifiedBy[directory].lastModifiedBy < lastModifiedBy) {
      filesByModifiedBy[directory] = { file, lastModifiedBy };
    }
  }
  return Object.values( filesByModifiedBy ).map( v => v.file );
}
```

and then you could integrate it with your current workflow like in the following way

```
gulp.task('compile', function() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    glob('src/jade/**/*.js', async function( err, files ) {
      if ( files ) {
        const newest = await filterByNewest( files );
        resolve( 
          src( newest )
            .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
            .pipe(dest('dist'))
        );
        return;
      }
      reject( err );
    })
  });
});
```